# How to manage , track or synchronize aynchronous multiple server requests in objective-c?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, download, asihttprequest

I am making **e-NewsPaper** app for both iphone and ipad which supported both for iOS 6 and iOS7.

In the app , there will be 1 week of **news** to display(in 1st view) and each news contains 10 to 15 **news pages** and 30 to 40 **articles** for those pages (in the 2nd view). So each news contains 10 to 15 **images** and 30 to 40 **xml** articles (i.e to be parsed and displyed in webview).

I am using `ASIHttpRequest` **for requesting and downloading images and xml** and `NSXMLParser` for **xml parsing**. I am using `UICollectionView` **for displaying News list** in cells.

There is **multiple news downloading in asynchronous way**. Also user can **play - pause -resume** (start - stop -cancel) this downloading in between by clicking button on each cell. There will be also one **progressview** to indicate downloading progress on each cell.

**I am doing following tasks/steps to download and display news and its articles ;**

```
1) Call PHP webservice and parse its JSON response and get News Paper list i.e going to display in collectionview of 1st veiw.

2) On clicking of any News Paper (i.e on collectioview cell), parsing will be started for that news's xml file.

3) Then with parsing of that file, the images and xml files are going downloaded in document directory.
```

I am able to download single as well as multiple news (with their images and xmls) but could not be able to identify , manage or track which news's images and xmls are downloading or downloaded among multiple news due to it is asynchronous.

I need to track , identify each news's request uniquely  (with its images and xmls downloading process) so that i can play-pause downloading.

I have searched a lot but could not be able to handle this.

Please help me...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I'v never worked with `ASIHttpRequest`, im used to `AFNetworking`. Either way, i just checked `ASIHttpRequest` documentation and they seem to use NSOperations just like `AFNetworking` for handling requests. Maybe you could map your operations with any id you have in your models. If this works for you then it will be very easy to cancel, pause, resume any operation, just looked them up where you stored them and perform tasks over them.

Hope it helps.